# Laravel 10 everySecond Method doesn't work as expected

Tags: laravel-10, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs, laravel-scheduler

According to laravel 10 documentation, we can use other sub-minute time constraints (everySecond, everyTwoSeconds, etc) for intervals lesser than one minute; but none of the sub-minute seems to be working as expected.

I have a very simple scheduled job below (strategic test 1)

`protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule): void { $schedule->job(new StrategicTest1)->everySecond(); }`

And my StrategicTest1 class below:

`class StrategicTest1 implements ShouldQueue
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

```
/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 */
public function handle(): void
{
    $st = Stretegy::find(1);

    $st->comment1 = random_int(1, 400);
    $st->code = 'st testing'.random_int(1, 400);

    $st->save();

    //echo 'done cats testing';

}
```

}`The`everyMinute()`method works fine; but`everySecond()`or`everyTwoSeconds()`doesn't work. Instead I receive`BadMethodCallException`error:` BadMethodCallException

Method Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\CallbackEvent::everyTwoSeconds does not exist.

at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php:113
109▕      */
110▕     public function __call($method, $parameters)
111▕     {
112▕         if (! static::hasMacro($method)) {
➜ 113▕             throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
114▕                 'Method %s::%s does not exist.', static::class, $method
115▕             ));
116▕         }
117▕

i   Bad Method Call: Did you mean Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\CallbackEvent::everyTwoHours() ?

1   app/Console/Kernel.php:33`

Am I missing anything?